# I'm getting this page when I run iOS simulator, and I'm wondering how to fix it and un-pause the app

Tags: xcode5, ios-simulator

Here's a link to the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMJzc.jpg

I don't have any breakpoints activated, and the few times iOS simulator even works for me, I get this page. I don't know what to do to fix whatever the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add exception breakpoint in breakpoint navigator, It will show where the crash is happening.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but I didn't really see anything different when I ran it a second time- it looks like the only thing is that green line in the screenshot (Except it also says breakpoint 1.1). I tried hitting 'Resume program execution', but now when I click on the app in iOS simulator it just goes back to the page with the app on it, instead of entering it.